# MVC5 external login

Tags: asp.net-mvc, external, facebook-login, membership-provider, owin

Unable to login using external providers such asd Facebook and LinkedIn in MVC 5 website.
After clicking onlogin it redirects back to /Account/Login#*=*. using owin authentication
Works fine locally but not on live server.

Comment: I have a very similar problem at the moment but on localhost too.